# AWS with Chinese and Japanese Character File Names uploaded but with ? in file name

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat, jakarta-ee, amazon-s3

Looking for a solution interesting problem.
Problem : When User uploading the file through the application, which has chinese/Japanese file name, some times(Most of the times) such file names where Chinese/Japanese characters exist are replaced by ?. We have many nodes and this is happening on only one node. And on other nodes when we did inspection, found it is happening some times but as happening as with our node I was talking about.

Looked in to all character set which is showing en_US.UTF-8. and it is same across the application.

Application is build on J2EE and using Tomcat on AWS server. Can any one please suggest any ideas where to look or any good solution that need to be done.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this issue?

Comment: No not yet, still investigating